# fetching only part of a Drupal 6 menu

Tags: drupal, menu

I'd like to pull out just one section of my navigation menu - a single section of the admin menu structure. I can load the entire navigation menu tree, but I can't see an easy way of pulling out just one segment of it.

Is there an easy way to do this, or do I have to do something hacky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand the situation, but you may want to take a look at [Menu Block Split](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block_split) which allows you to split levels of navigation into blocks. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... split any menu block into two different blocks: a first block with the first level menu entries only and a second block with any second level and sub level menu entries. You can have as many splitted blocks as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at function [menu_navigation_links](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/menu_navigation_links). You pass it a menu name (default = *navigation*) and a level (default = 0).

Comment: Thanks, but not what I'm looking for. I need a way to specify a root node for the tree that's not the root. `menu_navigation_links` gives me no way to display only `admin/content` and its children.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you'd consider this an *easy* way, but you could try to grab the whole menu tree via [menu_tree_data()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/menu_tree_data/6) or [menu_tree_page_data()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/menu_tree_page_data/6), find and extract the section you're interested in from the resulting tree structure and render the resulting subtree via [menu_tree_output()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/menu_tree_output/6).

**EDIT:** Stumbled over [*How to rendering a menu subtree*](http://drupal.org/node/249257) in the meantime - looks like my suggestion could work, but I would definitely not consider this being easy ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found this [here](http://drupal.org/node/193828) which works great for me.

```
<?php
$menus = menu_tree_page_data(menu_get_active_menu_name()); //get menu tree for active menu
  $output='';
  foreach($menus as $data) {
      if(!empty($data['link']['in_active_trail'])){
        $link = theme('menu_item_link', $data['link']);
        $extra_class = NULL;
        if ($data['below']) {
          $output .= theme('menu_item', $link, $data['link']['has_children'], menu_tree_output($data['below']), $data['link']['in_active_trail'], $extra_class);
        }
        else {
          $output .= theme('menu_item', $link, $data['link']['has_children'], '', $data['link']['in_active_trail'], $extra_class);
        }
      }
  }
  return theme('menu_tree', $output);
?>
```